# Android SDK emulator doesn't run my programs?

Tags: android

I recently got introduced to Android via a school course. Did some very simple examples earlier, and decided to installed all the required peripherals at my home computer too. I was on my way to develope all kind of cool stuff, until i noticed that something is wrong with my Android SDK or the emulator itself - it won't run any of the programs i try to.

I've got Eclipse & All the required add-ons / plugins installed. I get no error messages at any stage ( in eclipse or in the emulator itself ). Whenever i press run at Eclipse, the emulator takes it's time and starts up, but doesn't start the program, and doesn't actually show even the slightest hint of it. Looks just like if i had tried to start only the emulator. I've tried to create several different AVD's, and tried to use different versions of Android on them. No luck.

Im using windows 7 x64, and after a couple of rounds with Google, i found a few other guys who are having the same problem with the same OS.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as im running out of options here.

Answer (score 1):

You need 32 bit eclipse and 32 bit JVM. There should be an error in the "console" window in eclipse if you hit run.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Menu button of the emulator to unlock it.  You may then need to rerun the app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Tried this before, and tried it again. No luck, unfortunately.

Comment: From your log, it looks like the emulator is never found.  Note my console output yours stops before a line like 
[2011-01-14 13:33:15 - MyProject] New emulator found: emulator-5554  Perhaps, try running by right-clicking on the project name and selecting Run As Android Application

Comment: Uninstalled Android SDK and Eclipse, and tried this after the reinstall. Still the same result. I believe i need to try the 32-bit eclipse and JVM, since i still haven't tried that...